# pandas: boolean selecting rows by index (DatetimeIndex)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I have created a DataFrame for keeping energy logger data. Right now this DataFrame is only storing some random numbers. As index I use a `pandas.core.indexes.datetimes.DatetimeIndex`. With the `weekday` attribute I can figure out the corresponding weekday (0 for monday, 1 for tuesday and so on...).

I don't expect there to be any energy consumption on weekends. My correspondign code looks about:

```
# weekday > 4 => saturday and sunday
df.loc[df.index.weekday > 4, 'power'] = 0
```

This works fine. But let's say, there is no consumption on wednesday and thursday. I would expect the corresponding code to look like:

```
df.loc[(df.index.weekday == 2 or df.index.weekday == 3), 'power'] = 0
```

This doesn't work. I get the following error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Ok, pandas hints me at these methods `any` and `all`. But as far as I understand, they don't do what I need - or at least I don't know how to use them for my needs.

**QUESTION:**

Does anybody know, how to get such a DataFrame slice determined by some boolean condition?

Many thanks in advance!

**P.S.:**

I have figured out a solution - but it's very uncomfortable:

```
df.loc[df.index.weekday == 2, 'power'] = 0
df.loc[df.index.weekday == 3, 'power'] = 0
```

Just imagine, I want to do the same thing for a couple of hours or minutes instead of days. There has to be an easier way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combinations of conditions in these cases have to be joined by `&` (AND) or `|` (OR) and the single conditions have to be put in parentheses.

`df.loc[(df.index.weekday == 2) | (df.index.weekday == 3), 'power'] = 0`

should work

Edit based on comment:
This can be extended to more days by using the `isin(list)` method:
`df.loc[(df.index.weekday.isin([3,4,5])), 'power'] = 0`

Comment: But still a lot of typing, if I want to do this for more days. Is there another more elegant solution?

Comment: Glad to hear that. Feel free to upvote and accept my answer. Yes, you can extend this by using `df.index.weekday.isin([list of days])` as your condition

Comment: PERFECT! :) Thank you!